# AWK number of rows based on a certain row value

Tags: bash, awk

I want to keep only certain rows of a .txt file using UNIX Bash command, based of a "code" number:

```
Name  
Ignore  
2    
1357 1817  
1366 1857  
Name 
Ignore  
3   
293 142  
302 181 
303 181
Name  
Ignore  
7  
1596 1787  
1595 1787  
1594 1787  
1565 1803  
1565 1804  
1565 1805  
1565 1806
Other-name
No-interest
No-interest
No-interest
```

So only rows with "Name" is of interest. "Other-name" is of no interest. The SECOND ROW following "Name" is a CODE for how many rows are of interest for the "Name". But I dont want to keep all, only THE FIRST AND LAST row following the row with the code. So if the code i 3, I want row 1 and 3 following the row with the code. If the code i 7, I want row 1 and 7 following the row with the code. In the ex. above the output should be:

```
1357 1817  
1366 1857    
293 142  
303 181
1596 1787    
1565 1806
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks pretty similar to [what you you asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860305/delete-certain-rows-in-text-files-using-unix).

Comment: Looks like you want lots of things. Any efforts of your own to resolve this?

Comment: I know guys, Im sorry. Im struggling to find the best way of solving a hard nut.

Comment: Y, its pretty similar, but that way just made more downstream troubles. So I have to do another approach.

Comment: Of course I try to solve it myself, I have used countless hours. I just asking here in hope of good input! If this one work however, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
awk -f ext.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your input file and `ext.awk` is

```
/^Name/ {
    getline
    getline
    n=$1
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        getline
        if (i==1 || i==n) print
    }
}
```

Comment: Im totally new to this, how do you make "ext.awk" from what you wrote?

Comment: Just open a file in a text editor and paste the code into it and save the file as `ext.awk`..

Comment: Nice :) I need no payment, `awk` is just fun :)

Comment: Hold on.. One thing did not work, it only prints out the FIRST row following the row with code, not also the LAST. So I only get half the values I should had..

Comment: @user2966591: it works here with GNU awk, nawk and FreeBSD awk. I just noticed that you have an error in the desired output, the last line should be `1565 1806` and not `1565 1804`.

Comment: Good spotted! Thanks. Im running osx mountain lion. I should install nawk maybe?

Comment: Installed gawk (http://code.google.com/p/rudix-mountainlion/downloads/detail?name=gawk-4.0.2-0.pkg&can=2&q=gawk) and it worked like a charm!! Love this forum<3 Thanks!